# Function to delete an element from an array not working

Tags: c++

I wanted to write a function which upon being called deletes an element from an array given that the parameters passed in the `deleteArray` function were the array, its length and the value of the element to be deleted.

Tried breaking out of the `for` loop while transversing through the array if the element was found and then tried using `i`'s value in another `for` loop to replace the current elements with their next element.

like `array[j] = array[j + 1]`

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void deleteElement(int[], int, int);

int main() {

    int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 6 };

    int length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]); //For length of array

    deleteElement(array1, length, 4);

    cout << "\nIn main function\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << array1[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

void deleteElement(int array2[], int length, int element) {

    int i = 0;

    for (int i; i < length; i++) {
        if (array2[i] == element) {
            for (int j = i; j < length; j++) {
                array2[j] = array2[j + 1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == (length - 1)) {
        cout << ("Element doesn't exist\n");
    }

    cout << "Testing OP in deleteElement\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << array2[i];
    }
}
```

**Expected:**

```
Testing OP in deleteElement
14356
In main function
1356
```

**Actual:**

```
Testing OP in deleteElement
14356
In main function
14356
```

Comment: `int i=0; for(int i;i<length;i++)`: You are clobbering your initialized `int i` with an uninitialized one.

Comment: You can't 'delete' elements from an array -- arrays have fixed size in C and C++.  You can only move elements around.  Moving down elements like this will still leave the last element in the array, duplicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is rather silly:

At the beginning of `deleteElement()`, you define `i` with `int i = 0;`, but you redefine another variable `i` as a local index in each `for` loop. The `for` loop introduces a new scope, so the `int i` definition in the first clause of the `for` loop defines a new `i`, that *shadows* the variable with the same name defined in an outer scope.

```
for (int i; i < length; i++) {
```

And you do not initialize this *new* `i` variable.

There are 2 consequences:

- undefined behavior in the first loop as `i` is uninitialized. The comparison `i < length` might fail right away.
- the test `if (i == (length - 1)) {` tests the outer `i` variable, not the one that `for` iterated on. Furthermore, the test should be `if (i == length) {`

There are other issues:

- the nested `for` loop iterates once too many times: when `j == length - 1`, accessing `array[j + 1]` has undefined behavior.
- you do not update `length`, so the last element of the array is duplicated. You must pass `length` by reference so it is updated in the caller's scope.

Here is a corrected version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element);

int main() {

    int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 6 };

    int length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]); //For length of array

    deleteElement(array1, &length, 4);

    cout << "\nIn main function\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << array1[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (array2[i] == element)
            break;
    }

    if (i == length) {
        cout << "Element doesn't exist\n";
    } else {
        length -= 1;
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            array2[i] = array2[i + 1];
        }
    }

    cout << "Testing OP in deleteElement\n";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << array2[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the algorithm function [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), you can accomplish this in one or two lines of code without writing any loops whatsoever.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element) 
{
   int *ptr = std::remove(array2, array2 + length, element);
   length = std::distance(array2, ptr);  
}

int main() 
{
   int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 6 };
   int length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]); //For length of array
   deleteElement(array1, length, 4);
   for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      std::cout << array1[i];
}
```

Output:

```
1356
```

Note that we could have written the `deleteElement` function in a single line:

```
void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element) 
{
   length = std::distance(array2, std::remove(array2, array2 + length, element));
}
```

Basically, `std::remove` moves the removed element to the end of the sequence, and returns a pointer to the beginning of the removed elements.

Thus to get the distance from the beginning of the array to where the removed elements are located, usage of `std::distance` is done to give us our new length.

---

To remove only the first found element, `std::find` can be used, and then `std::copy` over the elements, essentially wiping out the item:

```
void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element) 
{
   int *ptr = std::find(array2, array2 + length, element);
   if ( ptr != array2 + length )
   {
      std::copy(ptr+1,array2 + length, ptr);
      --length;
   }
}

int main() 
{
   int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 9 };
   int length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]); //For length of array
   deleteElement(array1, length, 4);
   for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      std::cout << array1[i];
}
```

Output:

```
135469
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but the semantics are subtly different: `std:remove` removes all occurrences of `element` in the array, whereas the posted code in the question removes just the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for multiple loops in `deleteElement`. Additionally, your removal will fail to remove all elements (e.g. `4` in your example) if your array contains more than one `4`, e.g.

```
    int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 4, 5 };
```

You can simplify your `deleteElement` function and handle removing multiple occurrences of `element` simply by keeping a count of the number of times the element is `found` and by using your counter as a flag to control removal, e.g.:

```
void deleteElement(int array2[], int& length, int element)
{
    int found = 0;                      /* flag indicating no. element found */

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  /* iterate over each element */
        if (array2[i] == element) {     /* check if matches current */
            found += 1;                 /* increment number found */
            continue;                   /* get next element */
        }
        if (found)                          /* if matching element found */
            array2[i-found] = array2[i];    /* overwrite elements to end */
    }

    length -= found;    /* update length based on no. found & removed */
}
```

Updating your example `main()` to show both pre-delete and post-delete, you could do something like the following:

```
int main (void) {

    int array1[] = { 1, 4, 3, 4, 5 };

    int length = sizeof array1 / sizeof *array1; //For length of array

    cout << "\nBefore Delete\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout  << " " << array1[i];
    cout << '\n';

    deleteElement(array1, length, 4);

    cout << "\nAfter Delete\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout  << " " << array1[i];
    cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Which in the case where you array contains `1, 4, 3, 4, 5` would result in:

```
$ ./bin/array_del_elem

Before Delete
 1 4 3 4 5

After Delete
 1 3 5
```

While you are using an array of type `int` (of which there are many in both legacy and current code), for new code you should make use of the containers library (e.g. `array` or `vector`, etc...) which provide built in member functions to `.erase()` elements without you having to reinvent the wheel.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **length of the array is never updated** after deleting. Logically the length should decrease by 1 if the element was deleted.
To fix this, either

1. Pass the length by reference and decrease it by 1 if the element is actually deleted. OR
2. Return from the deleteElement some value which indicates that the element was deleted. And based of that, decrease the value of length in the main function.

Recalculating the array length will not help because the element is not actually deleted in memory. So the memory allocated to he array remains same.

Other issues:

- The first for loop in deleteElement should run till j < length - 1.
- The for loop creates a local variable i, which shadows the i variable in outer scope, so the outer i is never updated and always remains = 0